How to Link Metrics Data with Traces Using Exemplars in Ruby?
I'm working on linking metrics data with traces, and I discovered that Exemplars can be used for this purpose.
In Go lang, I can achieve this with the following configuration:
go
if span.SpanContext().IsSampled() {
    traceID := span.SpanContext().TraceID.String()
    counter.(prometheus.ExemplarAdder).AddWithExemplar(1, prometheus.Labels{"trace_id": traceID})
}


Go implementation references this test code:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-go-contrib/blob/main/bridges/prometheus/producer_test.go#L116C1-L122C1
However, when I try to achieve the same in Ruby, I couldn't find any built-in support for Exemplars in the Ruby ecosystem.
My Questions:
Does Ruby have support for Exemplars?
If not, is there a recommended workaround to link metrics with traces in Ruby?
Any guidance or examples would be greatly appreciated
Exemplars support for ruby
